Android Credential Manager getCredential check is already saved account
After successful login of the user, I want to check if account of the user is not saved before, how can I check this, because now when user for example skip login with credential manager, or some error hide it and user logged without manager I want to show (do you want to save credentials) just in case there is no that credentials was saved before?
Get credentials function:
fun getCredential(context: Context) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val getCredRequest = GetCredentialRequest(
                listOf(GetPasswordOption())
            )

            val credentialResponse = credentialManager.getCredential(
                request = getCredRequest,
                context = context,
            )

            val result = credentialResponse.credential as? PasswordCredential

            if (result != null) {

                authorize(
                    context = context,
                    login = result.id,
                    password = result.password,
           //prevent to show save function if user login with credential manager
                    fromCredentialManager = true
                )
            }
        } catch (e: GetCredentialCancellationException) {
            Timber.e("CredentialLogs", "GetCredentialCancellationException", e)
        } catch (e: NoCredentialException) {
            Timber.e("CredentialLogs", "NoCredentialException", e)
        } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
            Timber.e("CredentialLogs", "Error getting credential", e)
        }
    }
}

Save credentials function:
    private fun saveCredential(context: Context, username: String, password: String) 
{
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            credentialManager.createCredential(
                request = CreatePasswordRequest(username, password),
                context = context,
            )
            Timber.v("CredentialLogs", "Credentials successfully added")
        } catch (e: CreateCredentialCancellationException) {
            //do nothing, the user chose not to save the credential
            Timber.v("CredentialLogs", "User cancelled the save")
        } catch (e: CreateCredentialException) {
            Timber.v("CredentialLogs", "Credential save error", e)
        }
    }
}


I am looking for close to the same thing. I can tell you that the Credential manager will check for you if credentials exist. If they do not, opening the login screen will open the dialog prompt to save them. I am currently using that on a "login" button click.
